# Правильный перенос: Алексан-дрия или Александ-рия?

Tags: стилистика, морфемика, существительные, перенос, грамотная-речь

**Александ-рия** - не получается ли при таком переносе разрыва слога?

И еще вопрос по переносу:

- **мучениче-ского** или **мученичес-кого**,

  - **собст-венного** или **соб-ственного**?

Answer (score 1):

Все приведённые в вопросе варианты переноса правильны.

См. ПАС:

§ 217. Группа неодинаковых согласных букв в середине слова, входящих в корень или образующих стык корня и суффикса, может быть разбита переносом любым образом, напр.: се-стра, сес-тра и сест-ра; це-нтральный, цен-тральный и цент-рольный; ро-ждение и рож-дение; де-тство, дет-ство, детс-тво и детст-во; шу-мный и шум-ный.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97